# How to count records using an l-tree

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `tickets` and `categories`. The `categories` table has 3 columns of interest: `id`, `name` and `path`. The data looks like this:

```
id | Name | Path   
------------------
1  | ABC  | 1
2  | DEF  | 1.2
3  | GHI  | 1.2.3
4  | JKL  | 4
5  | MNO  | 4.5
6  | PQR  | 4.5.6
9  | STU  | 4.5.9
```

Note that the `path` column is an [l-tree](http://patshaughnessy.net/2017/12/14/manipulating-trees-using-sql-and-the-postgres-ltree-extension). What this is meant to represent is that the category with `id=2` is a subcategory of `id=1` and that `id=3` is a subcategory of `id=2`.

In my tickets table, there's a column called `category_id` which refers to the `id` column in my categories table. Each ticket can have up to one category assigned to it (`category_id` may be null).

I'm trying to count all the tickets for each category.

Suppose my tickets table looks like this:

```
ticket_id | ticket_title | category_id
    1     |      A       |    1
    2     |      B       |    2
    3     |      C       |    3
    4     |      D       |    5
    5     |      F       |    5
    6     |      G       |    6
    7     |      H       |    9
```

I would like to output:

```
category_id | count
    1       |   3
    2       |   2
    3       |   1
    4       |   4
    5       |   4
    6       |   1
    9       |   1
```

I've found that I can get all of the tickets which belong to a given category with the following query: `select * from tickets where category_id in (select id from categories where path ~ '*.1.*');` (although now that I'm writing this question I'm not convinced this is correct).

I've also attempted to perform the ticket-count-by-category problem and I came up with:

```
SELECT
 categories.id    as cid,
 COUNT(*)           as tickets_count
FROM tickets
  LEFT JOIN categories ON tickets.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY cid;
```

which outputs the following:

```
c_id | count
 1   |   1
 2   |   1
 3   |   1
 5   |   2
 6   |   1
 9   |   1
```

I'm not very good at SQL. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH tickets_per_path AS (
SELECT
  c.path   AS path,
  count(*) AS count
FROM tickets t INNER JOIN categories c ON (t.category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.path) 

SELECT 
 c.id,
 sum(tickets_per_path.count) AS count
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN tickets_per_path ON (c.path @> tickets_per_path.path)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Which yields the following result:

```
id| count
1 | 3
2 | 2
3 | 1
4 | 4
5 | 4
6 | 1
9 | 1
```

It roughly works like this:

1. the WITH clause computes the number of tickets per path (without
   including the count of tickets of descendent paths).
2. the second select clause joins the categories table with the precomputed tickets_per_path view, but instead of an equi-join on path, it
   joins by testing whether a record in the left table (categories) is
   an ancestor of the right side table (using @> operator). Then it
   groups by category id and sums up the ticket counts by category
   including the descendant counts.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you need a more general `join`:

```
SELECT c.id as cid, COUNT(*) as tickets_count
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN
     tickets t
     ON t.category_id || '.' LIKE c.id || '.%'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

The `'.'` in the comparison is just so `1.100` doesn't match `1.1`.

Comment: Hmm, that's not working for me. See https://imgur.com/a/wTMEQUe. Maybe I'm doing something wrong though :(

Comment: Someone at my company found `select c.id, c.name, count(*) from categories c left join tickets t on c.path ~ ('*.' || t.category_id ||n'.*')::LQUERY group by c.id, c.name order by count(*);` but that aggregates the tree upside down. It gives category 3 has having 3 tickets and category 1 as having 1 ticket.